# JSON.stringify("only values, not hash/key nor markup")

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, stringify

I have a obj -> JSON.stringify().

```
newString = '<pre>'+JSON.stringify(values, ['displayName'], 4)+'</pre>';
```

returns:
[image]

I only want to show the values for the key "displayName" without any of the array/obj markyp("{}, [], etc") ---> Alexander Thorarinsson

Example of obj depths in 'values' array:

[image]

Log for every cell value for the given table render:
[image]

Comment: So what is your expected output exactly? You just want the value of the one key?

Comment: Perhaps some more context would help

Comment: ---> Alexander Thorarinsson for the given example

Comment: So you what to convert an object to json but not display json? So why did you convert it to json in the first place? What did you think you'd achieve by doing that? Just access it like a regular object `values[0].displayName[0]`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` has no place here at all, whatever made you think it did?

Comment: Can't predict the depth of nested objects

Comment: Do you know the key? You need more examples of depth and what the output is.... The solution here would/may not work with other depths...

Comment: I'll ad examples with edit on quest.

Comment: Use [recursion to iterate an object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11922384/1169519) with unknown deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need stirngify, but you do need to unwrap the arrays carefully

```
newString = '<pre>'+values[0].displayName[0]+'</pre>';
```